# Will name change affect Brazilian visa (or passport in general)?

Tags: visas, passports, brazil

I recently got married. My wife, who will be changing her last name soon, has a Brazilian visa in her American passport from when she went in 2011 and I am under the impression that the visa is good for the duration of the passport (which doesn't expire until like 2019 or so).

I'm wondering if she changes her name, will that cause her to have to get a new passport and lose the visa? We are considering going to the World Cup next year, partially because she already has the visa anyway, so I want to make sure we don't screw up anything and lose it just because of a stupid name change.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Indian Visa in expired passport, new passport with husband's surname](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20085/indian-visa-in-expired-passport-new-passport-with-husbands-surname)

Comment: @HaLaBi: It's dangerous to suggest that Indian visa regulations are similar to Brazilian visa regulations. In this case, they do not match.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, she will need a new visa.

From the [Brazilian Consulate General in San Francisco](http://saofrancisco.itamaraty.gov.br/en-us/frequently_requested_information.xml):

> _**25. I got married and changed my name on my new passport, but my visa, which has not expired, is still on my old one. Do I need a new visa or
>   can I just travel bringing along the two passports?**  The name on the
>   visa has to match with the one on the valid passport. In this case, it
>   is advisable that you apply for a new visa in order to avoid problems
>   with the Brazilian immigration authorities.

Comment: Obviously not your fault but the language on the consulate's website is confusing. If it's merely “advisable”, then it does not seem to be a formal requirement.

Comment: @Relaxed this could be a translation *or* a cultural thing. Perhaps they are uncomfortable with saying "required" but are trying to *imply* that it is *advisable* to get a new visa if you don't want to get refused entry, in the same way that some people will say that it is *advisable* not to shoot people if you don't want to go to jail....

Answer (score -1):

If you undergo a legal name change due to marriage, divorce, or a court-ordered process, acquiring a new passport is necessary. Subsequently, the Department of State suggests applying for a fresh U.S. visa to facilitate smoother travel to and from the United States after obtaining your new passport.

Comment: The question is about a US passport and a visa from Brazil, your answer is about a Brazilian passport and a US visa. Can you edit please?