# Visa needed for Spain & Morocco

Tags: visas, schengen, morocco, south-african-citizens

My daughter is on a British passport, I am on a South African passport, living in UK on an ancestral visa.  If we travel to Spain and Morocco must I get a visa for each country?

Comment: Is the question if *you* need a visa? If so, is it somehow relevant that your daughter has a British passport?

Answer (score 2):

Based on available information you will likely need visa for both countries since you're traveling with the South African passport.  You can find relevant discusson on [Lonely Planet](https://www.lonelyplanet.com/thorntree/forums/europe-western-europe/topics/uk-ancestry-visa-and-schengen) as well as [this site](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/25196/valid-schengen-visa-in-unmarried-name-and-old-expired-passport-can-i-travel-wit) and [VFS Global](http://www.vfsglobal.com/spain/southafrica/) for Schengen, and [Visas Unlimited](http://www.visasunlimited.co.za/forms/requirements/morocco.html) for Morocco.

Answer (score 0):

You will for sure need a visa to Morocco. Beware that the deadline for applying for a Moroccan visa in South Africa: 1 month, and they are very strict about it.

Comment: Do you have any citations or references which explain or support this?