# Surname difference in Passport & Visa

Tags: visas, passports, b1-b2-visas

I am travelling to the US tomorrow. 
My surname in visa : Kanduri Rajani
My surname in my New Passport: Kanduri

My old passport expired and in the new passport, I changed my surname to 'Kanduri'
So, present surname in passport : Kanduri

Will there be any objection if there is a difference in surname in passport and visa?

Comment: I assume the visa is in the old passport and you will travel with both?

Comment: I assume Rajani is part of your name. If it's also in your passport (just not under "surname") then you should be fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Indian Visa in expired passport, new passport with husband's surname](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/20085/indian-visa-in-expired-passport-new-passport-with-husbands-surname)

Comment: @MarkMayo: Not a dupe, since that question is about traveling to India, while this about traveling to the US.

Comment: @jpatokal I get your reasoning, but what about Peru to Russia? Mali to Afghanistan? Are we going to have the same answer for every pair (40,000ish). The source/destination doesn't really matter, it's the passport/visa here, and it's (as far as I'm aware, happy to be proven wrong), the same for everywhere in this case.

Comment: @MarkMayo Unfortunately there are some countries (eg. Russia) that do *not* accept visas in expired passports: http://www.wordtravels.com/Travelguide/Countries/Russia/Visa

Comment: @jpatokal oh wow, fair enough, today I learned.

Comment: Did you face any problem while travelling?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you travel with both passports, you should be fine.

A name change is a fairly common event for people, particularly after marriage. Immigration will have dealt with it before.

However, you will still need to present the visa. Again this is a common enough activity, and presenting the old passport with visa, and the new passport as a valid ID, should be fine. I've done this before with two passports and a visa in the old one, and they didn't have any issue with this.

If you're concerned, bringing the documentation of your name change should provide absolute certainty.