# Name change on new passport, US visa still valid on old passport

Tags: usa, passports, passport-renewals

To match my degree name on O & A levels, I changed my passport name accordingly.
So now my old and new passport have different names. On my old passport I have my US visa, which is still valid.

Can I still travel? How can I book my tickets? My tickets will have a different name from my new passport.

Comment: Bring your old passport with the visa. Also bring the legal documents that show your name change. Also bring your new passport, of course!

Comment: @phoog 's comment is correct. See http://travel.stackexchange.com/q/20085/36405

Answer (score 3):

You can travel. Carry both passports, and a copy of the legal documents that show the name change. If the legal document isn't in English, you must have a copy translated by a sworn translator.

You can update your name on your visa with your new passport.

The [official line](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/general/frequently-asked-questions/about-visas-the-basics.html) is that it's recommended you get a new visa.

This [FAQ](http://www.ustraveldocs.com/pl/pl-gen-faq.asp#qlistgen10) on a pretty comprehensive Polish (it seems) web site explains it quite well.