# Traveling back from Bangladesh

Tags: visas, bangladeshi-citizens, bangladesh

I have an EEA family member visa in old, expired passport. I now have a new passport, issued by Bangladesh. Do I need to transfer the visa from old passport into the new one? Can I travel with two passports?

Will immigration in Bangladesh stop me for transferring the visa?

What I am supposed to do?

Comment: Nationality Bangladesh and Bangladesh passport but I have EEA family member visa and I want to go Bangladesh from uk.i know nowhere is problem to carry both passport but worried about bd immigration

Comment: Uk is fine only worried about bd immigration

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Valid Indian visa in an expired passport](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9234/valid-indian-visa-in-an-expired-passport)

Comment: Why would Bangladesh immigration even care about this?