# Qatar visa has old passport number

Tags: visas, passport-renewals, qatar

I have 8 months validity on the visa in my old passport. I renewed it recently; my new passport number and old one are different. When I applied for a visting visa to Qatar, I used my old passport number before renewing my passport. My visa came in my old passport.

Will it be a problem for me to travel, as my visa has the old passport number, and my new passport number is different?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Valid Indian visa in an expired passport](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/9234/valid-indian-visa-in-an-expired-passport) note the answer is country independent. This happens all the time. I have traveled with my USA visa in my expired passport countless times.

Comment: Most countries allow you to use a valid visa in an expired passport.  I don't know if Qatar is such a place.

Comment: @chx Qatar is not in India.

Comment: @phoog edited my comment. This is not country specific.

Comment: @chx of course it is.  Every jurisdiction is free to set the conditions under which its visas are valid.  For example, the European Court of Justice ruled just three years ago in [AS Air Baltic Corporation v Valsts robežsardze](http://curia.europa.eu/juris/liste.jsf?num=C-575/12) that a visa in a cancelled passport is still valid.  If there were some widely accepted general principle that this were the case, such a ruling would not be necessary.

Comment: Voting  to keep open. Things can be different for Qatar.

Comment: Do you have also the old passport?

Comment: @phoog I've added a question inspired by the comments: https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/92310/is-there-at-least-one-country-where-short-term-visitors-cannot-use-a-visa-in-the

Comment: This is not always the case. I have a Malaysian one year multiple entry visa, stamped on my passport. It is not valid if I renew the passport. Its specifically written on that.

Answer (score 3):

I have had this happen with me. You just carry both passports with you and show them the valid passport with the valid visa on the old passport.